# Keep an Nginx alive after a bash script

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently trying to execute a bash script inside my Nginx container and then keeping it alive of course.

So, my idea was to do what I need to in the bash script and as the last command, the command found with a `docker-compose ps`. But the container keeps shutting down. Here is a summary of what I currently have

The Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY ./run.sh /root/run.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/root/run.sh"]

CMD ["/root/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
nginx -g daemon off;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to use: `nginx -g "daemon off;"`, with the option quoted.

Comment: It simply was that... Thanks :) Maybe post it as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use: `nginx -g "daemon off;"`, with the option quoted.